# Flow: How to type a HOC that accepts a prop the wrapped component doesn't care about

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I'm not quite sure how to type the following HOC in Flow 0.57.3:

```js
// @flow
import React, {Component, type ComponentType} from 'react';

type OwnProps = {
    onFoo: void => void
};

// What we want from the returned wrapper component:
// - enforces presence of `onFoo` prop
// - enforces the prop contract of the passed-in WrappedComponent
function WithOnFoo<Props: {}>(
    WrappedComponent: ComponentType<Props>
): ComponentType<Props & OwnProps> {
    return class WithOnFoo extends Component<Props & OwnProps> {
        componentDidMount() {
            this.props.onFoo();
        }

        render() {
            return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
        }
    };
}

const MyComponent = ({name}: {name: string}) => (
    <p>Hi, {name}</p>
);

const wrapped = WithOnFoo(MyComponent);
```

Try it out [here](https://flow.org/try/#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).

The comment explains what I'm looking for: a returned wrapper component that

- enforces presence of `onFoo` prop
- enforces the prop contract of the passed-in WrappedComponent

Flow complains that:

```
20:             return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
                       ^ props of React element `WrappedComponent`. This type is incompatible with
11: function WithOnFoo<Props: {}>(    ^ some incompatible instantiation of `Props`
```

I'm not quite sure what this error is complaining about. I know I'm not taking pains *not* to pass the HOC's `onFoo` prop down to the WrappedComponent, but I'm not sure that's the source of the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: well, it is pretty easy to try `const {onFoo, ...props} = this.props;` and pass `{...props}` to `WrappedComponent` instead of `{...this.props}` just to rule that out.  In fact that resolves the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While `<Props: {}>` allows `this.props` to be spread , we have knowledge that `onFoo` should be part of the Props from the component that will be wrapped. So we should declare that the props of the component handed to WithOnFoo has `onFoo`, i.e.

```
function withOnFoo<Props: {} & OwnProps>(
    WrappedComponent: ComponentType<Props>
): ComponentType<Props> {
    // implementation here ...
}
```

Note also that `Props` is a "first-class" type within the implementation details of `WithOnFoo` (which will have onFoo). So you can replace where you have written `Props & OwnProps` with `Props`.

See [the flow example here](https://flow.org/try/#0PTAEAEDMBsHsHcBQBLAtgB1gJwC6gEoCmAhgMY4A0oA3gMKwawB2hTloOAnuoaPYyzYAVboQC+oSFgagA5FhLlZAbkSIQoFoQAmO0OmnoAzpOmpQAdSzF0Pbf0yC8kbKAAWyAOZvCWALTYugraoKQMjqx4OLCSAK5M5MjM+oa+0JyIXDwEhACOscjBAAqGJgC8NIig1aDMAGKwsABcoHXxicyIYqqIkO04SUyhxNDQRgDyTA2wkw7MkQAiyNoAsrDxOAA8JbDGLdQSAGQ5+YU6O8YAfAAUVTVWNnZzTi3PkSI826WXiACUr+F5sJRF9dkZLpUaqAFDhYlghqRoMQjCZaCMxpNprNAU4lqt1mxQIQAB44VjaVE4yKgq6QqE1MICRbLNYba6-On0+k4DxGAB0BjBfPqjXZqi51TEagl0PJvnZnJlsth8NAmweth0b0J1D5ep5yH5guMEmAl3FEqlUO6XTUYSYRjwK042rwFWu1CYxFQ4n2Xp9LUdWGQTE8Yg5ZQhm3QlwAEsgqJ7veJNsAYz17Y7LNZNSEKqR0RMpo1sUy2HjWWxrs7Xb8ehohLBPJ5oCHPLUWBwfJJYKMEG2UrAAG6EEzrPDoZFGYCQYjIaCgIykVjEYOwIxqDRFKej9RgTN4NzEJjaaCEaagd0RiEHVQadU5uyaZNlaiybco2QSEWwV9Hk9ntMprmpuYAaHUc5jHuoTMFm-6nuejSXnITCwHgxBxAkAzMCo0EPo8ej+oQr6yBB85fh20x-seCFAaAZr1mBYBkVB94ak+REkSxFEMYgQA)

Note: I've modified some nomenclature to help myself understand your example

`WithOnFoo` becomes `callsOnFooOnComponentDidMount`

`OwnProps` becomes `RequiredProps`

Comment: Ahh, this is the right answer. I had been doing `withOnFoo<Props: {} & OwnProps` and then _continuing_ to do  `ComponentType<Props & OwnProps>` as the parameterized types within the HOC code, not realizing that `Props` was _already_ defined as that intersection.

Comment: Yes, those names made it hard to reason about! Good call to change them.

Answer (score 1):

Try removing `onFoo` from the props list when rendering the wrapped component.  seems to make the error go away.

```
render() {
  const {onFoo, ...props} = this.props;
  return <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
}
```

See [example](https://flow.org/try/#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)

Comment: Oh weird. I had tried shallow-copying `let props = {...this.props}` and then `delete props.onFoo` without success.

Comment: Here's the wild thing though: `const {...props} = this.props` ALSO works!

Comment: (and it properly validates the wrapped component's props)